# Use Mbedtls-SGX on Windows

Tags: windows, sgx, mbedtls

I have an application which has an Intel SGX Enclave. I want, from within the enclave, to create a https connection to a server (so that the session keys and other secrets are hidden in the enclave).

I saw the mbedtls-sgx github page (https://github.com/bl4ck5un/mbedtls-SGX) and I tried to build this library on Windows by changing some settings in the cmake files.

However, all my trials have been unsuccessful.

Did someone manage to use this library on Windows?

Or do you know another library I could use on Windows to build the client side of the https connection inside the enclave?

Comment: From mbedTLS documentation, ```In order to build for a Windows platform, you should use WINDOWS_BUILD=1 if the target is Windows but the build environment is Unix-like (for instance when cross-compiling, or compiling from an MSYS shell), and WINDOWS=1 if the build environment is a Windows shell (for instance using mingw32-make) (in that case some targets will not be available).```.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to run mbedTLS on Windows. My problem was when I tried to change the CmakeList of the SGX adaptation (the git project)  and configure it for Windows. Most of the flags were not recognized and I think I have a conflict between Intel SGX enclave stdio.h and windows stdio.h